# Use Java filter on stream with in a stream filter

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have `Item` and `Address` classes:

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    List<Address> address;
}

public class Address {  
    String name;
    String lane;
}
```

Suppose I have a item list and want to filter items that has lane as `"lane1"`.

I try below but in Eclipse it shows:

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Stream Address to boolean"

```
items.stream().filter(a->a.getAddress().stream().
      filter(b->b.getLane().equals("lane1"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) on the inner stream:

```
items.stream().filter(a->a.getAddress().stream().
      anyMatch(b->"lane1".equals(b.getLane()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Maybe `"lane1".equals(b.getLane());`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting type mismatch error because filter has to return boolean result and in your case inner stream is returning `Stream<Address>` not boolean.

So as answered by @Sweeper, you can use `anyMatch`,

```
// you can directly use predicate in anyMatch 
    Predicate<? super Address> equalsLane1 =  address->address.getLane().equals("lane1");
    List<Item> lane1 = items.stream().filter(ele ->
               ele.getAddress().stream().anyMatch(equalsLane1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```